# Upgrading Laravel 5.0 to Laravel 5.1 Commands to Jobs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.1 is renaming `Commands` to `Jobs` and `Events` to `Listeners`.
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/releases#laravel-5.1

I was using `Commands` and `Command Handlers` in Laravel 5.0 like so.

`app\Commands\MyCommand`

```
<?php namespace app\Commands;

use app\Commands\Command;

class MyCommand extends Command
{

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}
```

`app\Handlers\Commands\MyCommand`

```
<?php namespace app\Handlers\Commands\Genapps;

use app\Commands\MyCommand;

class MyCommandHandler
{
    public function handle(MyCommand $command)
    {

    }
}
```

I don't see how I'm supposed to implement the handler in Laravel 5.1?

Comment: I recently used Laravel Shift to [automatically upgrade Laravel 5.0 to 5.1](https://laravelshift.com/upgrade-laravel-5.0-to-laravel-5.1). Did this and so much more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the 5.1 [release notes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/releases#laravel-5.1):

> However, this is not a breaking change and you are not required to update to the new folder structure to use Laravel 5.1.

In case you want to upgrade, you just have to rename your folder and change the namespace (Laravel uses [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoloader in version 5, so the folder structure corresponds to the namespace of your files).

However if your project is quite large I do not recommend you that, since as the documentation states this is not required step for the upgrade your code will work just fine in 5.1. It is more like a cosmetic change.

Comment: Yes but this makes me really uncomfortable, it's almost guarantee this will become a breaking change in the future I don't expect they will keep backward compatibility forever so might as well fix this now.

Comment: @user391986 The documentation states the change is backwards compitable. If you want, then you can migrate. Create `app/Jobs` and `app/Listeners`, move your classes there, change namespaces and update all of your code to use the correct namespaces.